Route PulseAudio through multiple channels without loss of quality
I want to route PulseAudio through multiple output channels.
pactl list short sinks

0   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
1   alsa_output.usb-BurrBrown_from_Texas_Instruments_USB_AUDIO_DAC-00.analog-stereo module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED

pactl info | grep 'Default Sink'

Default Sink: alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.analog-stereo

pactl list cards

Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_0e.0
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 1
    Profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 60, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6060, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5400, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5460, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5260, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5260, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 160, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo
Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.usb-BurrBrown_from_Texas_Instruments_USB_AUDIO_DAC-00
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 2
    Profiles:
        output:analog-mono: Analog Mono Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 200, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6000, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digital Stereo (IEC958) Output (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:analog-stereo

I want to be able to route audio through 3 Profiles
output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo (Current Active Profile) in Card 0
output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo  in Card 0
output:analog-stereo in Card 1
aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev3 Analog [ALC662 rev3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: DAC [USB AUDIO    DAC], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

Currently only this produces sound
aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
I need it to route to hw:0,0, hw:0,3 & hw:1,0
How do I reroute this to all three?
IF there is any documentation I could look at that would be nice.
Update
I tried the following steps
pactl set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo 
pactl set-default-sink alsa_output.pci-0000_00_0e.0.hdmi-stereo

Now I hear audio when I play both
aplay -D plughw:0,3 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav
aplay -D plughw:0,0 /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Right.wav

So i tried to combine the 2 sinks
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,0 sink_name=analog
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink device=hw:0,3 sink_name=hdmi
pactl load-module module-combine-sink sink_name=combined slaves=analog,hdmi
pactl set-default-sink combined

And then I ran the following
paplay --device=combined /usr/share/sounds/alsa/Front_Left.wav
The first time i run this, it plays audio in both. But from the second time onwards it only plays in hw:0,0 or the analog sink.
I think the different profiles have different priorities and wonder if that plays a role in the output. I'm not sure which sources I need to check to read up about this behaviour.
